# Why does my columns in Datagridview switch around?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

My intention is to fill a data grid view and add an additional column with delete buttons for each row. When the form loads, the data grid view should also fill up.

But here's the part I don't understand. I use `RefreshOfficeList()` to fill up the DGV. If I put one on the form load event, the column for the delete button is placed in the zero index, or the left most. If I press the refresh button, it moves the third (last) index, or the right most. If I don't include it in the load event, obviously the DGV will be empty. And if I press the Refresh Button, it'll fill up the DGV, with the correct order, placing the delete button column on the 3rd index. I want to put one on the `Load` event, but I want it in the right order.

Need help in understanding this.

```
Private Sub frmOffice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sFormState = "Add"
    'RefreshOfficeList()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    RefreshOfficeList()
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshOfficeList()
    sql = "SELECT entry_no," & sOfficeCommittee & "from tbl_office order by office"
    SelectQuery(3)
    With dgvOffice
        .Columns.Clear()
        .DataSource = dt
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .Columns(0).Visible = False
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "entry_no"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Office - Committee"
        .Columns.Insert(2, AddDGVButton())
        .Refresh()
    End With
End Sub

Private Function AddDGVButton() As DataGridViewButtonColumn
    Dim dgvbutton As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    With dgvbutton
        .HeaderText = ""
        .Text = "Delete"
        .Name = "btn"
        .UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
        .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
    End With
    Return dgvbutton
End Function
```

Note: If anybody's wondering, `SelectQuery()` is just a sub for getting the data table.

Comment: Is the grid data bound before calling `RefreshOfficeList()` in load?

Comment: no. the DGV is filled programmatically. Even the columns and headers. No data source. Zero columns.

Comment: Are you on an old computer (possibly XP 64 bit)?   I seem to remember that originally, the DGV had to be shown before columns from a DataSource were generated.  At some point, that behavior changed.  Try moving the call to `RefreshOfficeList` to the Form.Shown handler.

Comment: @TnTinMn No, Windows 10 64-bit. Activated at that. I also thought this had to do something with how the program loads its objects sequentially. But I don't really know how to alter that. If there was an event like Form.Loaded, kind of like Form.Closing to Form Closed, that might have worked.

Comment: You should check out the documentation for the `DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex` property.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Correct me if I'm wrong, but all that does is change how the columns LOOK like. I need my columns to be in their respective spots. Otherwise I'm going to be extracting the value "Delete" instead of an actual ID value like "1" or "2". Also, it doesn't work. The columns look like they're in the right order. But index-wise, they're not.

Comment: You appear to be retrieving data from a database so you should be binding the grid to a data source.  In that case, any time you access the data should be through the data source, not the grid, so the order of the columns in the grid is irrelevant in that context.

Comment: What you just said counts as a solution. Thanks for that. Unfortunately what I'm looking for is an explanation. I want to know why this happens. I don't really like the idea of piling unexplainables or problems to the side.